# Storing the state of a VSTO Outlook plugin in a draft message

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I try without success to store the state of a VSTO plugin in a draft e-mail.
I add user properties on an MailItem.Write event (when I save the draft message) but I retrieve nothing when opening the saved draft on an MailItem.Open event.

Some code OK :

```
public bool Item_Write(ref bool Cancel)
{
    Cancel = false;
    string state = "OK";
    [snip]
    /* does work : "OK" seen with OutlookSpy on draft message */
    item.Categories = new string(state);
}

public bool Item_Open(ref bool Cancel)
{
    Cancel = false;
    [snip]
    /* does work : "OK" string retrieved (on debugger breakpoint) on draft double-click */
    string state = item.Categories;
}
```

Some code KO : no property retrieved

```
public bool Item_Write(ref bool Cancel)
{
    Cancel = false;
    string state = "OK";

    /* does not work */
    UserProperties userProperties = null;
    UserProperty pluginState = null;

    userProperties = item.UserProperties;
    if (userProperties != null)
    {
        pluginState = userProperties.Add("PluginState", OlUserPropertyType.olText, false, 1);
        pluginState.Value = new string(state);
    }
    
    /* does not work either */
    string proptag = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x003D001F";
    item.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(proptag, new string(state)); 
}

public bool Item_Open(ref bool Cancel)
{
    Cancel = false;
    string state;

    /* UserProperties does not work : pluginState == null on draft double-click */
    UserProperties userProperties = null;
    UserProperty pluginState = null;

    userProperties = item.UserProperties;
    if (userProperties != null)
    {
        pluginState = userProperties.Find("PluginState", true);
        if (pluginState != null)
            state = pluginState.ToString();
    }
    
    /* PR_SUBJECT_PREFIX_W does not work either : state == null on draft double-click */
        string proptag = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x003D001F";
        state = item.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(proptag);
}
```

I launch the plugin under Visual and in Outlook I just create a new mail, close it and answer yes to save the draft ...

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no `Application.ItemWrite` event. There is `MailItem.Write` event, but it passes `Cancel` (by ref) parameter, not `Item`. Ditto for `Application.ItemOpen`: there is no such event.

Try to remove a call to `mailItem.Save()` - your message will be saved immediately after the your event handler runs unless you set `Cancel` parameter to true. Try to use [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am it author - click IMessage button) to make sure your custom prop is indeed saved.

When reading the custom prop, since there is no `Application.ItemOpen` event, you can use `Application.Inspectors.NewInspector` event or `Application.ActiveExplorer.SelectionChange` event. `Application.ItemLoad` event is not a good option - it fires too often.

Keep in mind that a user prop can cause Outlook to send in the RTF (TNEF) format - to make sure that does not happen, use `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty/GetProperty`. You can use the same DASL property as the one used your your custom property (see the DASL name in OutlookSpy).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right, event names are wrong in my comment but I use the correct ones ;-) This code is extracted from real one, so "names have been changed" ;-) ... Anyway the 2 methods are called at the right times ... I download OutlookSpy and let's go checking what's going wrong ...

Comment: It is not just the names, the events are on different objects, which means how you set them up is important.

Comment: From what I saw in OutlookSpy, UserProperties are not saved :-( between the writing of the draft and its reopening in order to be sent ... Do you know if UserProperties are supposed to be saved between 2 executions of Outlook ?

Comment: Yes ... I verified I use the correct event names :-) I use a wrapper which is trigged on MailItem.Open (resp. .Write) and gives control to Application_ItemOpen (resp. ItemWrite) with the MailItem as parameter. The boolean output value of the Application_* methods is used to return cancellation status. Under debugger execution, all seems fine but .... nothing is saved :-(

Comment: Is it only the user property that does not get saved? Or any other property as well, such as Subject?

Comment: Only user properties

Comment: Try to set the property using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty` using the same DASL name shown for that property in OutlookSpy. When reading, use  `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`

Comment: I saw this kind of setting the options but it seems it's depending on activation of cached mode on exchange :-( so not usable, I don't know what configuration will be set on user side ...

Comment: what do you mean by "DASL name" ?

Comment: When working with raw MAPI properties and `MailItem.PropertyAccessor`, the property must be specified in the DASL format. E.g., `PR_SUBJECT_W` MAPI property (corresponds to `MailItem.Subject` in OOM) is `0x0037001F`, and its DASL name is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0037001F`. Do take a look at the MAPI properties in OutlookSpy (click IMessage button).